# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai.embeddings_utils'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ros, openai-api

I only get that error if I run the script as a service in ROS:

```
import openai
from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding, cosine_similarity

import sys
import rospy
from servicio_palabras.srv import WordCount

openai.api_key = "--"

def ask_user():
    context = {"role": "system",
                "content": "Command System parser."}
    messages = [context]

    petition = input("What do you want me to do?: ")

    messages.append({"role": "user", "content": petition})

    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="--", messages=messages)
    response_content = response.choices[0].message.content

    messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": response_content})

    return response_content

def word_count_client(sentence):
    rospy.wait_for_service('word_count')
    try:
        word_count = rospy.ServiceProxy('word_count', WordCount)
        response = word_count(sentence)
        return response.words
    except rospy.ServiceException as e:
        print("Service call failed: %s"%e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = ask_user()
    words = word_count_client(input)
    print("The words in the sentence are: ", words)
```

I have done `pip install openai` several times but i dont know where the problem is. I also have deactivated conda and done `catkin_make` and `source devel/setup.bash` in the terminal i am using.

Comment: What is your `openai` version?

Comment: try pip install `openai==0.27.7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### openai.embeddings_utils does not exist in latest openai 1.2.0

You can downgrade to:

```
pip install openai==0.27.7
```